# EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/logs/'

Tags: npm, nestjs

When I try running local server from `npm run start`, it shows this error.

I'm using Mac and NestJS.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to create your logs folder in the root of the filesystem which may not be allowed in MacOS

Comment: I think NestJs is trying to make a logs folder while running. Is there a way to get around it...by giving access to nest js somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Check your tsconfig.json file on `{"outDir": "/logs/"}` and replace with `{"outDir": "./logs"} or` {"outDir": "logs"}

Tags: `node` `npm` `express` `typescript`